# Minimal sufficient statistics for beta distribution

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be a simple random sample. Each $X_i, i \in \{1, \ldots, n \}$ has beta distribution $Be(\alpha, \alpha), \alpha >0$.
My task is to find the minimal sufficient statistics. I did it in the following way:
$$f(x_1, \ldots, x_n | \alpha) = \frac{1}{\mbox{B}(\alpha, \alpha)}\big(x_1 \ldots x_n (1-x_1) \ldots (1-x_n) \big)^{\alpha-1} \tag{1}.$$
Using the form $(1)$ I can conclude (using [factorization theorem](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/283/)) that my statistics $T(X)$ looks like this:
$$T(X) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i(1-x_i).$$
Now I need to show that $T$ is minimal.
$$U = \frac{f(x_1, \ldots, x_n | \alpha)}{f(y_1, \ldots, y_n | \alpha)} = \bigg( \frac{x_1 \ldots x_n (1-x_1) \ldots (1-x_n)}{y_1 \ldots y_n (1-y_1) \ldots (1-y_n)} \bigg) ^{\alpha - 1}.$$
$U$ is independent from $\alpha$ if and only if the fraction is equal to $1$. And that happens when $T(x) = T(y)$ thus $T(X)$ is minimal.
Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Essentially yes, though I am not sure that the general statement is "$U$ is independent from $\alpha$ if and only if the fraction is equal to $1$. And that happens when $T(x) = T(y)$ ..." I might prefer "$U$ is independent from $\alpha$ if and only $T(x) = T(y)$ (or one of then is zero) ..."

Comment: @Henry I think that the general statement would be a bit different. However in my case it is the only possibility that's why I wrote it this way.